# 500 returned from HTTP server from simple web application

Tags: asp.net, http, request

I have one **application on server A**. which is accepts XML data in HTTP requests and makefile from that HTTP request's data.
(***urlABC***)

My other **application server B** is used that URL ***urlABC*** and sending data on that URL using HTTP request.

Sending data in requestXml

```
Request sending code :  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.myurl.com/payment");
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
            return null;
```

but sometime Application on Server B gives **500 returned from HTTP server** but not getting any exception on Server A.

Server B Only sending data, using above function. nothing else.
Server A has all logic. but not given any error/exception.

Comment: look on your event viewer to locate the real error - can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Server A is acting as a gateway between the requesting client and Server B, Server A needs to process the HTTP status code of 500 (internal server error) that was returned by Server B and return an 5xx series HTTP code back to the client.

Either of these HTTP status codes in the response from Server A should work.

1. 500 - Internal Server Error (from Server B)
2. 502 - Bad Gateway (generated by Server A after processing the Server B response with a 500 HTTP status code in the response)